# ASP.net: What type of application/website is more suitable to Webform or MVC?

Tags: asp.net

I have read all the post regarding the pro and con of ASP.net webform vs mvc.

However, I'm wondering under what circumstance does one use webform or mvc? would it come down to what you or your team is more familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical business application with lots of controls, their behavior rules, with enabling/disabling them in response to the events fired by other controls would be a lot more complicated task with MVC while with WebForms you can do it during a coffee-pause.

Also with MVC you get nice SEO-friendly urls out of the box, which is great for publicly exposed sites. WebForms do not offer that convenience, however, for internal applications or the public ones protected by customer login it is no concern at all.

Comment: I would disagree that webforms are less suitable for public websites.. first, you can pretty much same SEO and avoid postbacks if you need to (routing, jquery, webmethods) but still reserve power of event driven environment, secondly even public website almost always have admin backend that would resemble your typical business app. So it's really matter of preference what you choose.. MVC or forms. I supppose one thing MVC excels is granular control over what you do (which though comes at cost of time and budget) and for really really really high load sites it could be more scalable way

Answer (score 0):

As time goes by, I find it very hard to use WebForms (against mvc) for anything new.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is asp.net webforms more suitable for application that use it in intranet (internal systems) because it have a bunch of controls. also if you implement a big Application.

Asp.net MVC Suitable for a websites that uses a lot of ajax and you want a SEO frindly urls.